# How do i retrieve the data using JSON from the Remote Database and display in my android app xml file?

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I am working with an app in which I am able to successfully send parameters to the remote database, but I am not able to figure out how to retrieve it into my xml file .

Can anyone know about it?
or can you all give me a reference code of retrieving data from database  using JSON?

Comment: Can you display what data are you retrieving. Like your XML file and your get parameter code.

Comment: i want to display list of details (e.g. details of patients) from the database to my xml file using JSON. i hope you are understanding what i am trying to tell. what should i write in java.class to retrieve data from database .

Answer (score 0):

here is what you need (retrieving/reading JSON data):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html

However, I didn't catch what you meant by "display in xml file".

Comment: Sorry you didn't understand what i meant to say, actually i am developing a app in which i am saving the "details of the patient" in the database and i want to display the "list of details of patient" in one xml file.

Comment: so i wanted a reference code to display the details of the patients in one xml file. i hope you got the point what i am trying to tell.